can't access an env var added in groovy script
Team, I want to capture a var remoteUrl value coming from jenkinsfile into groovy library that is passed from jenkinsfile and store it in env var to access later. but I can't seem to do it. any hint what am i missing?
def call(Map config) {
    for (param in ['credentialsId', 'remoteUrl']) {
        if (!config[param]) {
            error "checkoutGit(): missing parameter ${param}"
        }
    }
    env = ["REMOTE_URL=${config.remoteUrl}"]
    final GIT_YX_URL = "ssh://@git-YX"
    final LIB_GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL = "git://git-mirror:111/git-t"
    if (config.remoteUrl) {
        println "Git YX url passed in user job"
        env.add("GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL=${config.remoteUrl}")
        echo "GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL is: ${GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL}"
    } else {
        println "No Git YX url passed in user job, using Library defined Git Mirror URL"
        env.add("GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL=$LIB_GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL")
    }

my jenkinsfile is
def REPO_MIRROR_URL = 'git://git-mirror'
            steps {
                container('main') {
                    script {
                        checkoutUtil(
                            credentialsId: 'git-ssh',
                            remoteUrl: "$REPO_MIRROR_URL",
                        )
                    }


error am getting is
Git YX url passed in user job

Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 01e941fa-4301-4ccc-a4ac-f286eb1e7baa
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL for class: checkoutUtil
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:66)


Your immediate problem is this line:
        echo "GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL is: ${GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL}"

variable GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL is not defined anywhere.
Next, redefining `env like this is bad:
    env = ["REMOTE_URL=${config.remoteUrl}"]

env is already used by Jenkins to store current environment. Repurposing it for your globally scoped variables is confusing.
Finally, Jenkins shared libraries should be stateless. Don't save variables between calls. Someone will have to read your code at some point. Be kind to them.

thanks. are you stating i should do def GIT_YX_MIRROR_URL first? and for second env.add("REMOTE_URL=${config.remoteUrl}").
